# Fastest way to see if a number is between two values

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring+JPA

I have a table which has MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE.

I then have a service that has a input VALUE. What is the fastest/better way to know if the the VALUE is between MAX AND MIN VALUES?

```
@Autowired
private ValuesRepository valuesRepository;

public void calculateValue(double value) {
    List<Values> valuesList = valuesRepository.findAll();
    // ??
}
```

Edit Maybe is better to do the select already returning one row??

```
public interface ValuesRepository extends JpaRepository<Values, Long> {

    public Values // ??
}
```

Comment: Do you want a single value to be checked or all the values in the list returned by `ValuesRepository.findAll()`?

Comment: You want all the rows which satisfies the max and min conditions?

Comment: provide entity class to frame query or method

Comment: It's *always* better to do filtering server-side if it's practical. In many cases the database won't even have to load the records from disk.

Answer (score 1):

```
findReferenceFieldBetween(value1,value2);
```

suppose your Reference Field is **Value** then,

```
findByValueBetween(Your Max Value, Your Min Value)
```

Refer [Query with Jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)    for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can check value between two different fields by using GreaterThan and LessThan in JPA

Excluding boundary:-

```
public T findOneBySinceGreaterThanAndUntilLessThan(Long since, Long until);
```

Including boundary:-

```
public T findOneBySinceGreaterThanEqualAndUntilLessThanEqual(Long since, Long until);
```

Reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Spring Data does support `Between`.